# Working with LINQ to SQL and DataGridView

Tags: c#, linq

I have an application in which I'm using LINQ-to-SQL as a data source. I'm currently working on some extended functionality for retrieving records from the database, and I want to display these records properly in a DataGridView component. I already have the records displaying, but there are two issues I have with how they're displaying. Specifically:

1. The column names are the same as in the database. I would like to abstract this away from the user, as all they are doing is selecting the record they want to load into the application. Is there a way using LINQ-to-SQL to alias the column names when you display them in a DataGridView?
2. There are a lot of unnecessary columns displaying in each row in the DataGridView. Specifically, I am selecting a record from an "Identifier" table, which has relationships to various other tables, and these tables are appearing as objects in the record view. Is there a way to omit certain columns from the DataGridView?

I'd appreciate any help someone could give me.

Comment: Modify your Select Query (the command text).  If you want to change column names then use "Column 1 as ABC".  Also instead of using * reference the column names you want.  The asterisks is bringing in all the columns.

Comment: This is a LINQ query I'm using. "as" is not a valid LINQ query keyword.

Comment: Well you could change to use a SQL query and use DataAdapter to put results into a DataTable. Linq always the best solution.

Comment: A LINQ query works best for me in this situation.

Comment: Well you can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: Just because you only know how to do it one way doesn't mean that I can't find a solution that works in my situation...

Comment: Dynamically created query may help you. See [DynamicLINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), [ExpressionTrees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries).

Comment: You have to consider the amount of time it takes to write code.  I know everybody tries to get the existing code to work.  But at some point of time you have to consider the amount of time you wasted and go with a method that you know will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property value to `false`, which will prevent generating columns from datasource. Then add your desired columns to `DataGridView`, then set `DataPropertyName` properties of that columns to your datasource's columns names (for example, if its `DataTable` object - set `DataTable` column names[which you want to show]) for example:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col1", "Column1");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col2", "Column2");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col3", "Column2");
.  .  . 

dataGridView1.Columns["Col1"].DataPropertyName = "Col1NameFromSource";
dataGridView1.Columns["Col2"].DataPropertyName = "Col2NameFromSource";
dataGridView1.Columns["Col3"].DataPropertyName = "Col3NameFromSource";
.  .  .
```

Then just bind your source to `DataGridview`'s `DataSource`

```
DataTable table = /*Your "LINQ-to-SQL" query;*/
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Assuming, that your `table` contains `Col1NameFromSource`, `Col2NameFromSource`, `Col3NameFromSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a datagrid and datatemplate if you are on WPF

https://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Comment: I'm using Winforms, so unfortunately not. But in the future, I may convert to WPF.